# javascript not working after loops it is both same at while and for

Tags: javascript

I cant find what is wrong.

I can delete the last row but when I try to delete another row last row not deleted. I copy the other rows but not deleted the last row after it.

```
function deleteBasket(i){
var j = i+1;
var k,m ;
var mainTable = document.getElementById("checkList");
var rowsTable = document.getElementById("checkList").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
var bText,dText;
var firstValues;

if (j == rowsTable-1) {
    document.getElementById("checkList").deleteRow(-1);
}
else {
for (j=i+1; j<rowsTable; j++){
    m = j+1;
    k = j-1;
    bText = '<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="changeBasket('+k+')">Güncelle</button>';
    dText = '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="deleteBasket('+k+')">Sil</button>';
    mainTable = document.getElementById("checkList");
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[0].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[1].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = mainTable.rows[m].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[3].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[3].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[4].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[4].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[5].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[5].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[6].innerHTML = bText ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[7].innerHTML = dText ;
    //alert ("j="+j);
}   
    alert ("wHY");
    document.getElementById("checkList").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

}

I cant get the WHY alert message. I think the mistake is at

```
mainTable.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[0].innerHTML ;
```

this statement but I dont understand why?

when I disable them it works.

Comment: May I suggest you take a look at your browser console? JS stopping execution is in my experienced due to an error.

Comment: I check it. and I get
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
    at deleteBasket (index.php?p=yourOrders:469)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php?p=yourOrders:1) 
But table is ok. I use other buttons only delete button not working

Comment: Press F12 and see the console tab to check if there is an error

Comment: I Check but nothing I find. still same

Comment: "Cannot read property ... of undefined" indicates to me you are trying to change an element that does't exist like one at index -1.

Comment: Where is the line 469 that the error pointing to ?

Comment: Guessing that the issue is with your `m` variable exceeding the number of rows in the table when your loop reaches the last row `j`, but these sorts of things are hard to troubleshoot if you don't post the relevant (but minimal) html.

Comment: You are right I add an If close for last row for m. It is ok now. thank you both benvc and Andre

Answer (score 1):

```
for (j; j < mainTable.rows.length; j++){
    m = j+1;
    k = j-1;
    bText = '<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="changeBasket('+k+')">Güncelle</button>';
    dText = '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="deleteBasket('+k+')">Sil</button>';
//  firstValues = mainTable.rows[m].cells[0].innerHTML;
    if (m <= rowsTable-1){
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[0].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[1].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = mainTable.rows[m].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[3].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[3].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[4].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[4].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[5].innerHTML = mainTable.rows[m].cells[5].innerHTML ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[6].innerHTML = bText ;
    mainTable.rows[j].cells[7].innerHTML = dText ;
    //alert ("j="+j);
    }
    //document.getElementById("checkList").rows
}   
    //alert ("wHY");
    document.getElementById("checkList").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

Comment: Hello Tugrul. Welcome to SO. Please add some information text to your answer always. What did you do? Why is that a solution for the problem? So OP and future readers can better understand your solution.

Comment: I write my solution at comment but forgot at here. I write an if statement. Error is over. because there is no last line in it.